# SED script to remove whitespace from a region

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with a bunch of strings that looks like this:

```
new Tab("Hello World")
```

I want to turn those particular lines into something like:

```
new Tab("helloWorld")
```

Is this possible using SED and if so, how can I accomplish this? I figure I have to use grouping and regions but I can't figure out the replacement string.

This is what I have so far

```
sed -n 's/new Tab("\(.*\)"/new Tab("\1")'
```

Comment: all of them are `new Tab("some text with spaces")` ?

Comment: They may or may not contain spaces, but they will be in the same line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is not perfect: it assumes the line contains just `new Tab("some string blah blah blah")` and nothing else on that line. Here is my *remove_space.sed:*

```
/new Tab/ {
    s/ *//g 
    s/newTab/new Tab/
}
```

To invoke:

```
sed -f remove_space.sed data.txt
```

The first substitution blindly remove all spaces, the second puts back a space between *new* and *tab*.

You don't have to put this in a file, the script works on command line as well:

```
sed '/new Tab/s/ *//g;s/newTab/new Tab/' data.txt
```

Comment: Note also that the first character of the string is lower-cased.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not enough of a sed guru, but here's a piece of Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=new Tab\(")[^"]+/ lcfirst(join("", split(" ", $&))) /e'
```

Comment: sed doesn't support negative lookbehind, so it probably isn't possible to use this technique with sed.

Comment: I agree, particularly since I evaluate the replacement string as code.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was using awk but I came up with something I don't really like:

```
echo "new Tab(\"Hello World\")" | gawk 'match($0, /new Tab\("(.*)"\)/, r) {print r[1]}' | sed -e 's/ *//g'
```

Comment: The 3rd parameter to `match` (an array) is a GNU awk extension, so requires `gawk`.